# No puedo trabajar con Savitzky Golay

Tags: python, scipy

Hola estoy tratando de trabajar con la libreria scipy, pero tengo un problema para trabajar con el suavizador Savitzky Gola

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

lista=[1,4,5,8,9,10,25,30]

lista_2=[3,5,6,7,8,9,1]

yhat = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(lista_2, 61, 3)

plt.plot(lista, yhat)
plt.show()
```

cuando compilo el programa da este mensaje como error.

```
  File "savgol.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece que al cargar ese módulo intentó cargar una DLL, que es un archivo binario específico de windows, y no la encontró. Esto indica que la instalación de scipy.signal quizás no fue correcta. ¿Cómo lo instalaste? Te recomendaría usar anaconda que es una distribución de python y paquetes científicos con versiones ya precompiladas para Windows, que funcionan bien "garantizado".

Comment: @abulafia por medio del siguiente código "python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose"

Comment: @abulafia, ¿existe alguna solución?